# Excel ranking of duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ranking

I am ranking some repetitive data with `=IFERROR(COUNTIF($I:$I, ">" &I2) + 1, 0)` and `RANK` functions but I get

```
sum         rank
1.948730668 1
1.948730668 1
1.948730668 1
1.948730668 1
1.948730668 1
1.948730668 1
1.948730668 1
1.948730668 1
1.948730668 1
1.944370401 10
1.944370401 10
1.944370401 10
1.940616775 19
1.940616775 19
1.940616775 19
1.940616775 19
1.940616775 19
1.940616775 19
1.940616775 19
1.932373487 26
1.932373487 26
1.932373487 26
1.932373487 26
1.932373487 26
1.932373487 26
```

I am looking for the ranking output to be 
`1, 2 in place of 10, 3 in place of 19, 4 in place of 24`, and so on.

Do you know to get the wanted output?

EDIT: After seeing a couple of comments, I just want to say that data is not fully sorted. This is another example:

```
0.746083463 4401
1.585145695 448
0.917176157 3325
0.640143457 5222
1.061271163 2376
1.252380073 1351
1.43915555  804
1.800414518 134
1.500507287 626
0.96121049  3012
```

Comment: as a side note, you can accept answer (if it answers your question) by clicking the check mark on its left http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

Here's the trick (assuming your values are in column `A:A`):

In cell `B2`:

```
=1
```

In cell `B3` and below:

```
=$B2+IF($A3<>$A2,1,0)
```

Comment: I usually shorten it to `=N(B1)+(A1<>A2)` as `N` returns 0 for text

Comment: @Slai - that's probably the best solution - why not post an answer?

Comment: That's a brilliant syntax optimization!

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I have many excuses :] there is no mention if the data is fully sorted, and my version will fail a bit if `B1` is a number

Comment: @slai Data is not sorted, please see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one alternative in `B2` and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B1, MATCH(A2, A$1:A1, 0)), MAX(B$1:B1) + 1)
```

or a bit shorter (and maybe a bit slower) with `VLOOKUP`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,A$1:B1,2,0),MAX(B$1:B1)+1)
```

Comment: And what should be in B1? Data is not sorted.

Comment: @HelleThorning I was testing it with unsorted data starting from `A2` and headers in `A1:B1`

Comment: @HelleThorning then I don't know what the result should be. That is the result I expect based on the first example, and I don't understand the second example

Comment: In this example 561 should have rank 1, 11 rank 2, 8 rank 3, etc. It is the same as in my first example. The bigger the number it is, the higher rank it has.